# How to find optimizers with computer in this kind of minimax problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory, optimal-strategy, minimax

I have a minimax problem of the form $$\max_{\substack{u_1,\dots,u_n \ge 0 \\ u_1+\dots+u_n = 1}} \min_{\substack{v_1,\dots,v_m \ge 0 \\ v_1+\dots+v_m = 1 \\ v_{j_1} \le v_{j_2} \hspace{1mm} \forall (j_1,j_2) \in J}} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m c_{i,j} u_i v_j,$$ where $J$ is some (given) subset of $[m]\times[m]$ and each $c_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ (is given).

So it's a normal kind of minimax problem, except we have some inequalities amongst the $v_j$'s.

By the minimax theorem, there are $u^* = (u_i^*)_{i=1}^n, v^* = (v_j^*)_{j=1}^m$ that are ``best responses" to one another.

Let's assume our problem is such that there is only one such $u^*$.

**Question**: How can I quickly (in practice, on a computer) find $u^*$?

The values of $n$ and $m$ I am working with are actually very small (e.g. $n \le 7, m \le 14$). However, Mathematica seemingly takes forever to compute the minimax, even with $n=2,m=4$.

Using Mathematica, I can find (some) $v^*$ rather quickly by interchanging the max and the min, and then noting that the max of the double sum over the possible $(u_i)_{i=1}^n$'s is simply a max of the double sum over the $n$ tuples $(u_i)_{i=1}^n$ with exactly one $1$ (and the rest $0$). However, this doesn't help me find $u^*$.

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152922/755, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270651/40712.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Which site do you think is most appropriate for this question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.